# how do I run cmd from the git post-commit hook

Tags: git, msbuild, continuous-integration

I want to have a miniature ci loop on my private projects and was thinking if I could run msbuild inside a batfile I could have colorized feedback on the cmd window and automate the build. So if I could just trigger the bat from the post - commit hook I guess it would be possible. It can´t possible be a new idea but I can´t find any examples on google.

any input would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Calling the `.bat` file from your post-commit hook doesn't require any magic.

Rename the post-commit hook template in `.git/hooks/post-commit.sample` to `.git/hooks/post-commit` and call the batch file within by simply writing the name of the batch file:

```
#!/bin/sh
path/to/batchfile.bat
```

Please note that the working directory for the git hook is the *root directory of your repo*. If you use relative paths to your `.bat` file, you have to take this into account.

Comment: thanx - I guess I _did_ think it was more complicated :)

Comment: Beware that already the `@echo` in the first line of your .bat file will make this approach fail because in this approach the .bat file is run as if it were a bash script. See [Duncan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15537025/177710) for a working solution.

Comment: -1 for it's incorrect. Though `batchfile.bat` with the extension `.bat` here, it's actually run as a bash script.

Comment: huzzah for pointing out `the working directory for the git hook is the root directory of your repo`

Comment: In 2020, using git 2.23 on Windows, this answer works as stated. That is, my batch does not run as a bash script, I had no problem with `@echo`, and had no need to run with `cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 41):

@eckes' answer was close but actually was running my bat/cmd files as if they were bash scripts. If you want to run them as batch files, here is what worked for me:

#### post-receive

```
#!/bin/sh
# important that it's got the .exe on the end!
cmd.exe /c "C:\path\to\somebatch.cmd"
```

#### somebatch.cmd

Here's some stuff/envrionment variables etc that you might find useful:

```
@echo off

:: read commit hook stdin data e.g. "aa45321… 68f7abf… refs/heads/master"
set /p OLDREV_NEWREV_REFNAME=

echo Directory of this script is %~dp0
echo Repository root is %CD%

set OLDREV=%OLDREV_NEWREV_REFNAME:~0,40%
echo OLDREV: %OLDREV%

set NEWREV=%OLDREV_NEWREV_REFNAME:~41,40%
echo NEWREV: %NEWREV%

set REFNAME=%OLDREV_NEWREV_REFNAME:~82,999%
echo REFNAME: %REFNAME%
```

Comment: Works great! can i run a batch from the same folder as the hook without full path? cmd.exe /c "somebatch.cmd" didn't work

Comment: Try `cmd.exe /c "$(pwd)\somebatch.cmd"`

Comment: BEWARE that for some reason, unlike in commands from the normal prompt, here the **CASE** is important! `cmd.exe /C` doesn't work, only `cmd.exe /c`!!! It took me half an hour to figure it out. It'd be better to add this to the answer (I'll wait for some confirmation from others before doing it myself).