# Git - How to auto push changes in a directory to another branch

Tags: git, github, configuration

**Complete question rewrite**

So I thought I was explaining this question very simply and direct but it seems I oversimplified to much, so here is all the extra details. Hopefully this helps everyone see this is also not a duplicate.

---

I have a repository (project) where I would like to automate the process of pushing commits from one directory in a branch to another branch; something I have not come across yet on SO.

Here is my project with its complete structure:

```
[PROJECT MASTER BRANCH]
|- gh-pages    (directory)
|- css         (directory)
|- index.html  (file)
|- readme.md   (file)

[PROJECT gh-pages BRANCH]
|- (empty at the moment)
```

What I am hoping to do is create a hook that will automatically handle changes in my gh-pages directory from the master branch, and copy/ clone/ replace them (whichever term is correct to use) into by gh-pages branch, the projects website branch. Here is an example with all other files left out:

```
[PROJECT MASTER BRANCH]
|- gh-pages         (directory)   <=== SEE UPDATE BELOW [A]
|  |- css           (directory)
|  |  |- style.css  (file)
|  |- index.html    (file)

[PROJECT gh-pages BRANCH]
|- css           (directory)   <=== SEE UPDATE BELOW [B]
|  |- style.css  (file)
|- index.html    (file)
```

I am completely new to this level of Git Hub. I normally just stick to the basics and never use the terminal/ shell. So in summary to clarify what I am hoping to do, I would like to:

- Only have to work in the [Master Branch]. All changes I need to make to [gh-pages Branch] I do in the gh-pages directory of [Master Branch]
- Preferable accomplish this by adding a simple file which seems to be a post-receive hook?

Here is some post-receive hook code that I tried using (I made it from studying a few things) but it doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
    if [ "master" == "$branch" ]; then
        git checkout gh-pages
        git checkout master -- gh-pages
        git add gh-pages
        git commit -m "Updating project website from 'master' branch."
    fi
done
```

**NOTE**
As mentioned in my comment: This is not a duplicate. This is not asking how to push but rather how to tack on other commands that auto run when I do a normal push. These commands would do the extra work mentioned in my OP.

**UPDATE**
I have added these arrows to parts of my code I refer to below: <===

**[A]** What should happen here is that Git should recursively read the master branches gh-pages directory and only copy from that what has updated (or everything if that is easier) into the gh-pages branch.

**[B]** So if the gh-pages directory in master has an index.html file and a css folder with a style.css file is should only copy over that structure not the gh-pages directory itself. Below is an example of a bad hook that copies the gh-pages directory too:

```
[PROJECT gh-pages BRANCH]
|- gh-pages         (Directory)   <=== NOT SUPPOSED TO HAPPEN
|  |- css           (directory)
|  |  |- style.css  (file)
|  |- index.html    (file)
```

Also, the hook should not copy over any other files but what is inside the gh-pages. Even if several other files changed in the master branch only the gh-pages directory files should be copied over.

**[C] NEW CODE - This works but causes an error:**

```
#!/bin/bash
branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
if [ "master" == "$branch" ]; then
    git fetch && git checkout gh-pages
    git checkout master -- gh-pages/*
    git add -A
    git commit -m "Updating project website from 'master' branch."
    git push -u origin gh-pages
fi
```

This wont work for two reasons. 1) If the repo is behind on commits it cant handle that, it will error out; if a pull is used instead of a fetch the local repo gets wiped like so:

[image: Local repo has been wiped when changing code to pull.]

If I leave fetch the local repo stays the way it should:

[image: Local repo the way it should stay after a push. Fetch was used here.]

2) The whole gh-pages directory gets copied over to the gh-pages branch still and not just the files inside it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automatically push after committing in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925850/how-to-automatically-push-after-committing-in-git)

Comment: @gzh this is not a duplicate. This is not asking how to push but rather how to tack on other commands that auto run when I do a normal push. These commands would do the extra work mentioned in my OP. [That question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925850/how-to-automatically-push-after-committing-in-git) is about automating the whole Git cycle every time the user hits commit, not committing to master and simultaneously cloning a directory into a whole different branch.

Comment: It seems that you need to write a post-receive hook to do this task.

Comment: @gzh bump. Reworded the question. Post-receive hook makes sense but I am lost at how to implement that.

Comment: The hook script is expected to be under $your_repo/hooks/post-receive directory, then what is the running directory for your hook script, and where your checkout code will be put? I think you should create a new folder, clone the source and do what you want.

Comment: It is there and I have 0 experience coding these. You could answer the OP with a working example. At least I learn by working off code than creating it from pieces. I use git for windows to push all my commits by the way.

Comment: It is not convenience for me to write working example for now, but [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401303/how-do-i-run-cmd-from-the-git-post-commit-hook) is some hook sample running on windows. Good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You really don't need this complex approach.

Simply add your own repo as a submodule (of itself!), submodule following the `gh-pages` branch (since [a submodule can follow the latest commit of a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309))!

```
git checkout master
git rm -r gh-pages # save your data first
git submodule add -b gh-pages -- /remote/url/of/your/own/repo
git commit -m "ADd gh-pages branch as submodule"
git push
```

That way, you can change files either in your main branch, or in the `gh-pages` folder (which is actually a submodule)

Whenever you are making changes in `gh-pages` folder, don't forget to commit there, *and* in the main folder of your repo in order to record the new **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** ([special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)) reprsenting the new SHA1 of the `gh-pages` submodule.

```
cd myrepo/gh-pages
# modify files
git add .
git commit -m "modify gh-pages files"
cd .. # back to myrepo folder
git add gh-pages
git commit -m "record gh-pages new SHA1"
git push
```

[With git 2.7+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10878273/6309), you can set:

```
cd /path/to/main/repo
git config push.recurseSubmodules on-demand
```

Then a single `git push` from your main repo will *also* push the `gh-pages` submodule to the `gh-pages` branch.

Later, a single `git clone` would clone both your main repo *and* its `gh-pages` branch (in the `gh-pages` submodule folder).

That way, you always have both content visible.

And you don't need a complex "synchronization/copy" mechanism.

---

Update August 2016: **[Simpler GitHub Pages publishing](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing)** now allows to keep your page files in a subfolder of the *same* branch (no more `gh-pages` needed):

[image: Now you can select a source in your repository settings and GitHub Pages will look for your content there.]

You don't need the submodule approach anymore, since your pagers can be in a subfolder within the same branch.

Comment: Note: that is an old approach I mentioned back in 2011 (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8148319/6309), based on [Mark Longair](http://stackoverflow.com/users/223092/mark-longair)'s answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5296433/6309). But at the time, submodules did not follow branches, and you could not push everything in one go.

Comment: You lost me here: "Whenever you are making changes in gh-pages folder, don't forget to commit there". If I run your code in shell it works but if I try to do a normal commit of any kind with Git for windows (desktop) I get an error saying to add the submodel with shell or remove the .git file

Comment: I tried this answer but no dice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542910/how-do-i-commit-changes-in-a-git-submodule

Comment: @Blizzardengle I have detailled the "dn't forget to commit there" step. And I have added the commit you must do after the initial `submodule add`. Clone your repo again, and try again those steps. (in command line only. GitHub Desktop is a GUI which wraps and obfuscates what is really going on: you don't need it)

Comment: I have been up all night trying to modify this and only have two things to say. 1) Its works, thank you. 2) It does not answer my OP where I asked for a non-shell solution. My goal and burning desire is to use Gits window GUI and not the shell every time. I made a pre-commit hook and even a pre-push hook to auto commit the submodule changes before my GUI commits and no dice. But again if I did that manually in the shell it works...not happy with it but it works.

Comment: It will work with any Windows GUI using a recent 2.7.1 git. It will work with GitHub Desktop when that GUI will end up using a recent enough git embedded in it (as I well know, you cannot change its git version: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33703716/6309). Embrace the command line: you can script it and make the all process "push-button".

Comment: I'm embracing the command line begrudgingly. I know its always the best thing to use, thanks for your answer. I think it is the best auto-project-website setups I have seen.

Comment: @Blizzardengle Again, if you have a GUI which calls a recent enough git (Like Tortoise Git, SmartTree, ...), all the command line you need is the initial `git submodule add`, and the `git config push.recurseSubmodules on-demand`. Everything else can be done from the GUI. Not from GitHub Desktop though.

Answer (score 3):

What's the problem with the hook script you wrote ? What were the contents of the branch gh-pages when you created it?

I had created an empty branch gh-pages with below command:

```
git checkout --orphan gh-pages
git rm -rf .
touch README.txt
git add README.txt
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin gh-pages
```

Then I ran below script as a part of post-receive hook and it worked for me.

```
#!/bin/bash
branch=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` 
if [ "master" == "$branch" ]; then
    git fetch && git checkout gh-pages
    git checkout master -- gh-pages
    git add -A
    git commit -m "Updating project website from 'master' branch."
    git push -u origin gh-pages
fi
done
```

Comment: I don't understand your code so I think you may have misunderstood. For some reason my hook wont run but if I run all that myself in shell it kinda works. All it did was copy every changed file from my whole master branch into gh-pages which is not what I need. https://github.com/blizzardengle/barebones-framework

Comment: I edited my question to point out the part that is not working.

Comment: This never worked as is because branch=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` needs to be $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD). It also copied over more than what it was supposed to, namely the gh-pages directory. It is a quick solution and can be consider an answer but @VonC answer hits the nail more on the head.

Comment: we would make a shell to handle the expected task as I suggested yesterday. However I agree VonC's answer is the deserving one ..