# How to keep two master lines?

Tags: git

### My situation:

I'm coding on a project, called `project`, now it's **half-done**.

But at this moment, I'm asked for another project, called `project-cn`, 80% same as `project`, but there are still different features to be develop.

### My solution for now:

1. new branch **`master-cn`** from **`master`** branch of `project`;
2. develop the unique features of `project-cn` under **`master-cn`**;
3. checkout back to  **`master`** branch, develop new common feature of both;
4. **Manual** copy the new feature modify to the **`master-cn`**.

### My expectations：

```
           project-hk
             /   \
            /     \
       master   master-cn
         /           \
        /             \
add feature-hk-1     add feature-cn-1
     |                    |
     |                    |
add feature-hk-2     add feature-cn-2
     |                    |
     |                    |
     |    feature-both    |
     |      /      \      |
     |merge/        \merge|
     |    /          \    |
     |   /            \   |
     |  /              \  |
     | /                \ |
   master              master-cn
```

### My Question:

What should I do ? And where is the **`feature-both`** from ? A new branch ? Base on where?

Comment: You could have your feature_both branch as a submodule of your own repo (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/35307501/6309)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a good idea to maintain both a `master` branch and a `master-cn` branch.

Only make commits on `master` that can live on both branches. After you add a feature on `master` merge it into the `master-cn` branch.

Eventually, when `master-cn` is finished, merge it back into `master` so `master` effectively becomes `feature-both`.

For this step:

> Manual copy the new feature modify to the master-cn.

I would do this:

```
git checkout master-cn
git merge master
```

BUT, if there are commits on `master` that simply cannot go to `master-cn` yet you may want to `cherry-pick` individual commits over:

```
git checkout master-cn
git cherry-pick a2j233 # sha
git cherry-pick vsdd3f # sha
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jonathan.Brink. But how about there are commits on `master-cn` that simply cannot go to `master`?

Comment: @smallyin if that is the case, then you may need to have a separate branch `feature-both` as you stated in your original question. It would be nice to integrate everything back into `master` so you can just maintain a single line of work, but I understand that's not realistic in some cases

Comment: @smallyin So, is it possible to periodically merge `master` into `master-cn` and use that as your feature branch, rather than having a separate `feature-both` branch? Just looking to cut down on the number of branches to be maintained