# How to place readme.md on the top of the page

Tags: github

I wrote a readme.md file for my git page. Now I wanna advertise for my program on some forums. I don't want to always update every single forum entry, so I though I just link to my git repo and they people can get the information about my tool just by reading the readme (in the future, all I need to is update this single file).

However, the source files are placed on the top and 99% of the people that will visit my repo won't have a clue about code. Therefore it would attract people more if they just see the readme.md instead of code (which might scare them away "oh I don't get it and it looks to hard to get a fast overview *leave*").

Is there a way to switch the code section with the readme.md section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to switch the code section with the readme.md section?

There is not for now in a classic GitHub repo.

One workaround would be to limit the number of top elements to a minimum, moving all those folders into a `src/` or `project/` subfolder.

That would make the code section very short, and the `README` (just below) that much more visible.

A different repo, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36099814/how-to-place-readme-md-on-the-top-of-the-page/36099936#comment59843219_36099936) by the [OP TrudleR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2311557/trudler), is available with [GitHub pages](https://pages.github.com/), like a [project site using the gh-pages branch](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually/).

For that approach, I like to [declare that branch as a submodule in the master branch of the same project repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35307501/6309): that way, I can update my project pages while updating the sources of the project itself.

---

Update August 2016: **[Simpler GitHub Pages publishing](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing)** now allows to keep your page files in a subfolder of the *same* branch (no more `gh-pages` needed):

[image: Now you can select a source in your repository settings and GitHub Pages will look for your content there.]

Those pages can be in a subfolder of the same branch now.

Comment: I just found out about "git pages" which seems exactly like what I am looking for. :)

Comment: @TrudleR I agree, and have updated the answer accordingly. I have added a tip to be able to work both on the project itself and on its pages at the same time.