# Copying Doxygen Documentation from gh-pages branch into a subfolder of Master branch

Tags: git, github, doxygen

Currently I have a Travis build that generates Doxygen documentation and then uploads this into a `gh-pages` branch on my GitHub. We also have a website that is currently being built from the `master` branch not `gh-pages.`

What I would like is a script to run after the Travis build passes that copies over the files from the `gh-pages` branch into a subfolder of our web files in `master` from which we can adjust the website to link to the documentation.

Is this possible or would it be easier to simply upload the documentation into master from the start?

Answer (score 1):

You can go on as is (upload the documentation in the gh-branch), but add one more step:

```
 git submodule update --remote
```

You can [declare a branch content as submodule of another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35307501/6309)

```
git checkout master
git rm -r gh-pages # save your data first
git submodule add -b gh-pages -- /remote/url/of/your/own/repo
git commit -m "ADd gh-pages branch as submodule"
git push
```

Since that [submodule will follow the latest commit of its own branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309), a `git submodule update --remote` done in `master` will be enough to update the content of the `gh-pages` subfolder (root directory of the submodule).

---

Note: [Since August 2016, **you can publish your pages right from the `master` branch**](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing) (not always the `gh-pages` branch)

That would simplify your issue.

Comment: @Akhila Single folder indeed. So no multiple GitHub site possible, at least from what I understand.