# How to keep ignored files when switching to branch not ignoring them?

Tags: git

I'm trying GitHub pages with a webpack project, so I made a new branch (forgot to use `--orphan`) and keep different files in them.

- On `master` branch, `dist/` directory is `.gitignore`d.
- On `gh-pages` branch, all files are ignored except for `dist/`, `index.html` and some other files.

When I `npm run build` on `master`, the new `dist/` is built, but it is overwritten by the former `dist/` when I checkout `gh-pages`. How to keep them and make it possible to add and commit them after?

Comment: Use two separate worktrees. Or even a submodule, but that's not necessarily required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the possibility of using two separate worktrees, you can use the [`git worktree`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309) command: that avoids having to maintain two different clones.

Don't forget also "[Simpler GitHub Pages publishing](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing)": you can maintain your pages in the same branch as the rest of your repo, in a `docs/` sub-folder.
That way, you don't need to switch branches at all.

Comment: What if your gh-pages isn't a doc of your app, but a demo? Can you tell Github to look to the `dist` directory instead of `docs`?

Comment: @EdmundReed in that case, you can use gh-branch instead, and declare (in the master) branch dist/ as a submodule (whose url is your gh-branch repo URL!) See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40967706/6309. That way, you have both content available in the same worktree.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the better practice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45931127/6202760), I have found a way to do the file transferring directly.

1. On `master` branch, after committing everything and doing the build;
2. `git add --force dist/`
3. `git stash`
4. `git checkout gh-pages`
5. `git stash apply`
6. Unstage `.gitignore` in case it is also transferred
7. Solve the conflict

However, it requires too many steps to be useful, and maybe simply `cp` them would be much easier.

Comment: I still think separate worktrees or a single worktree with docs looks much easier.