# How to deploy a subfolder in repository to Heroku via Travis CI?

Tags: git, heroku, travis-ci, git-subtree

I have a project repository containing 2 folders: server1 and server2. I want to deploy the contents of server1 to heroku automatically as I commit them to my github repository. I do not have a CI set up currently, but am looking for Travis specific steps.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the steps described in "[Heroku Deployment](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/heroku/)"

> Travis CI can automatically deploy your Heroku application after a successful build.

```
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  api_key: ...
  app: my-app-123
```

In your case, you would:

- [deploy a specific branch](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/heroku/#deploying-specific-branches) which would have `server2` content in it
- reference the content of that branch in your `master` branch as a **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**

See "[Can I use Git submodules to keep a copy of one branch inside a directory of another branch in the same repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51166069/6309)"

That way:

- TravisCI can deploy `server2` content, since it is a branch
- you can work in `server2` subfolder in your `master` branch, since `server2` subfolder is the root folder of a **submodule**, which would reference the content of the `server2` branch!

Again: that involves re-organizing your repository, in order to isolate the content of `server2` folder in its own branch, and reference that branch as a submodule, stored in the path `server2/` in your `master` branch.

Comment: Submodules seemed complex, so I dug around for a bit and settled on changing the document root in my procfile, but that's created some issues of its own.
Thanks for the info.

Comment: @KaustubhBadrike No problem. Submodule should be trivial to implement here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51166069/6309 include the relevant commands.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else is struggling, this fixed it for me, in the parent directory have your `travis.yml`
In your `travis.yml`  add `before_install: cd (your folder, like frontend)`

For example :

```
language: node_js
node_js:
- node
before_install: cd Web
install: ...
```

I also had a Procfile in my front end folder with `ProjectName: node server.js`