# How to git push folder to branch partially?

Tags: git, github, travis-ci, github-pages

Basically, I use `travis-ci` to locally build an entire site into `/dist` folder of `master` branch (but not upload to remote repo) and then deploy to `gh-pages` branch.

`travis-ci` supports pushing `local-dir` to `target-branch`: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/pages/

My site consists of several independent sections, so I expect in future that I only build one section if changed and incrementally deploy to `gh-pages` without affecting other sections.

For example, `/dist` has two sections `/dist/section_one` and `/dist/sections_two`.

On `master` branch, I make modifications to `/src/section_one`, which will be built into `/dist/section_one`. Then I can push it to `/section_one` on `gh-pages` branch. Is this practical?

Answer (score 0):

One trick is to have one's master branch referencing the `gh-pages` content as a submodule, in a `/gh-pages` *subfolder*: see "[Copying Doxygen Documentation from gh-pages branch into a subfolder of Master branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40967706/6309)".

That way, Travis-ci can:

- build /dist/section_one
- copy the result in `/gh-pages/section_one`
- add and commit and push within the `/gh-pages` subfolder
- add and commit and push within the main repo root folder, in order to record the new SHA1 of the `gh-pages` subfolder submodule repo.