# push with git subtree to project root

Tags: git, github, subtree

I am currently working on a github pages project and generate the website to a folder named `dist` on a branch named `dev`. I want to push the content of dist to the master branch. Googling around I found github subtree and I could push the `dist` directory to `master` using the command:

```
git subtree push --prefix dist origin master
```

issue is this pushes the entire directory. So master branch has one directory named `dist`, containing `dist/index.html` etc. Instead I would like to push all the content of dist to the master branch. So that the master branch contains `index.html` and all other content. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not easily done (beside doing some [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) magic)

If you have a look at "[Configuring a publishing source for GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/)", you should instead generate your site directly in the `gh-pages` branch.

Or, you can stay in `master` branch, but generate in a `docs/` folder instead of `dist`.

In both cases, GitHub pages will render that content.

However, for a [**User Page**](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#user-and-organization-pages-sites):

> If your site is a User or Organization Page that has a repository named `<username>.github.io` or `<orgname>.github.io`, you cannot publish your site's source files from different locations.
>   **User and Organization Pages that have this type of repository name are only published from the `master` branch**.

In that case, reverse your workflow:

- develop your site on a `dev` branch,
- generate your site on the `master` branch

When you are in your `dev` branch, **you can declare the `master` branch as a submodule** (see [here for the procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40967706/6309)), which will therefore be visible as a "subfolder" (for example a "`dist`" subfolder, except that subfolder will actually be your same Git repo, on `master`)

Generate your site as usual (in `dist`), go in dist, add, commit and push (that subfolder being a submodule, it will push on its associated branch: `master`)
Then go back to your project repo folder (parent of `dist`, currently on the `dev` branch), add, commit and push (to record the new state of the submodule `dist`)

Comment: I had some issues with merge conflicts earlier and ran the command


    git push origin `git subtree split --prefix docs master`:master --force

which strangely worked as it just pushed the content of docs. I don't really want to run that every time however.

Comment: @Marc Sure, but subtree is not the recommended way to have a generated set of files published with GitHub pages: use one of the official documented branch or folders that I mention in the answer.

Comment: the issue is if you have a User page you can not use folders och gh-pages branch for some reason........

Comment: @Marc Indeed: "If your site is a User or Organization Page that has a repository named `<username>.github.io` or `<orgname>.github.io` , you cannot publish your site's source files from different locations. User and Organization Pages that have this type of repository name are only published from the `master` branch."

Comment: @Marc I have edited the answer to propose an alternative which would preserve your current way of working (generating the site in a `dist` subfolder)