# Adding github pages to all subfolders?

Tags: github, github-pages

I have a repository in github which will house all of my web development assignments in separate sub-folders like :

> VishnuVelukutty/ CourseraWebdevAssignment (master)/ module2-assignment (subfolder)

So the master branch has gh-pages and I want to add the gh-page to all sub-folders (Assignment1,2,3 .....) independently so that they work independently when the specific module-link is opened

Is it possible to apply gh-pages to a subfolder ? or do I have create independent repo for each module ?

I have not initiated .gitignore, static site, readme nor theme and reffered to this post by [cobyism](https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490) and [chrisjacob](https://gist.github.com/chrisjacob/833223) but i didn't get it working

Here is my [github account to see if there any errors in setting up](https://github.com/VishnuVelukutty/CourseraWebdevAssignment.git)

For reference of the images here is the [git link](https://github.com/VishnuVelukutty/Testingrepo.git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure to create a `gh-pages` branch, add at least one commit in it and push it to your GitHub repository.

*Then*, yes, you can add that `gh-pages` branch content as a subfolder of your current repository, in the `master` branch, using [`git submodule`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).
(unless, as explained here, you [chose the `master` branch itself as source for GitHub Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12049125/6309))

```
git checkout master
git submodule add -b gh-pages -- /remote/url/of/your/own/repo gh-pages
git commit -m "Add gh-pages branch as submodule"
git push
```

You will have a `gh-pages` subfolder, that you can update at any time with:

```
git submodule update --remote
```

Comment: I used that technique many times before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40967706/6309

Comment: i followed the steps you mentioned but i am still unable to get it right (so if it possible for you to look into my github account above and correct me it would be really helpful)

Comment: @VishnuEzhuthachan Your repo looks good. You just need an `index.html` in your gh-pages branch/folder for anything to be visible in your GitHub page.

Comment: But the index file is inside module2-assignment and that doesn't display

Comment: @VishnuEzhuthachan I don't see that file (for instance in https://github.com/VishnuVelukutty/CourseraWebdevAssignment) Do you have an URL?

Comment: https://github.com/VishnuVelukutty/CourseraWebdevAssignment/tree/master/module2-assignment

Comment: @VishnuEzhuthachan But that is not the gh-pages branch you mention in your question, it is the master branch. Did you configure your master branch to host pages? (as in https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#choosing-a-publishing-source)

Comment: I don't understand how to do this.. can we create a separate github site for each subfolder ? But under the settings option of the repo you can only select a single folder right? @VonC