# Can git track a file in a branch-independent way?

Tags: git, branch

In my research project, I have code files and a Markdown file called `journal.md` where I write all my thoughts, meeting notes, etc. I have different branches that allow me to work on different parts of the project without affecting the rest. I would like the journal file to be the same on every branch: I want it to contain everything I wrote in it so far, regardless of the branch that was checked out when I wrote these things. I can think of two ways to do that, but they have big drawbacks:

- do not track the journal.md file: the issue is that I would like this file to be saved on Github with the rest, so it's backed up and I can pull it if I ever work from another machine
- get the most recent version of the journal.md file whenever I change branches (e.g. by checking it out from the branch where I made the latest changes): that's a pain and I will definitely forget to do so

Is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Worth noting: tracked-ness is not *branch*-dependent but rather *commit*-dependent. It's the *current commit* that's *branch*-dependent. So tracked-ness is the result of a chain of items, not *directly* a result of a branch. All methods of sidestepping this amount to putting the file into a different repository (even if that "different repository" is this same repository, re-cloned).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, provided `journal.md` is seen in its own folder by other branches, and is maintained alone in its own dedicated branch.

That is an old trick where:

- you have a file (`journal.md`) in its own branch named, for instance, '`journal`', alone;
- you declare in each of your other branches a submodule of another branch ([seen first here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35307501/6309))

That is:

```
git submodule add -b journal -- /path/to/your/own/repo journal
git commit -m "Add journal branch as submodule"
```

That will create a folder `journal/` with the content of the branch (`journal.md`)

At any time, you can do a `git submodule update --remote` and that folder `journal/` will be updated with the latest commit of the `journal` branch (meaning the latest content of `journal.md`)

If you `git config --global submodule.recurse true`, a simple `git pull` in your own branch [would be enough](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49427199/6309).

Comment: You can do this without going the separate-repo route. Make a branch and directory for it, `git worktree add` it, then `git add` the new versions as you make them.

Comment: @jthill Sure. I prefer the submodule approach, where any commit made in each branch *also* records the state of the journal branch at that time.