# How to disable Github branch protection rule for certain/auto-generated files

Tags: github

I have a git repository where some of the configuration files are auto-generated by scripts and pushed to the main branch. I like to enable branch protection rule to protect the main branch but like to disable these rules for certain file patterns.

Whether this is possible in Github?

Comment: this is not possible. you could have a pr process

Answer (score 2):

While it is not possible, you could isolate those auto-generated script in their own folder.

And that folder could be a submodule (as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35307501/6309)), referencing your own repository, but following a different branch, one which is *not* push-protected.

```sh
git submodule add -b scripts -- /url/to/your/own/repo scripts
git commit -m "Add script branch as submodule folder"
```

From the main branch, a `git submodule update --remote` would pull the latest of the `scripts` branch into the `scripts` subfolder.