# Git post-commit hook: How to start a bat-file in Windows

Tags: windows, git, batch-file, jenkins

i having a bat-file with name `jenkins.bat` to start building process on a jenkins server.

Now I want to execute this bat-file as post-commit-hook in git.

Therefore a created following file `post-commit` in the folder `/.git/hooks`:

```
#!/bin/bash
/.git/hooks/jenkins.bat
```

But eclipse throws me every time an exception when commiting code changes to git! Did I miss something?

Comment: Remove the leading `/` before `.git`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use either an absolute or relative path

- absolute: /c/...
- or, as commented, relative, meaning not starting with a `/`

  ```
    ./jenkins.bat
  ```

Assuming your post-commit hook is executable, and in the `<repo>/.git/hooks` folder, where your `jenkins.bat` appears to be.

---

As [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/63209/paul) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46697870/git-post-commit-hook-how-to-start-a-bat-file-in-windows/46701655?noredirect=1#comment112471937_46701655)

> Doing `./jenkins.bat` does *not* work when the batch file is in the hooks directory: you will get a "`no such file`" error.
> This is because of the [hook's working dir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7402697/6309).

Comment: What do you mean with 'executable'?

Comment: I have to point out that doing `./jenkins.bat` does *not* work when the batch file is in the hooks directory: you will get a "no such file" error. This is because of the [hook's working dir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7402697/63209).

Comment: @Paul Thank you, good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Also @user3133542: on Windows, nothing. This is probably a reference to how in Unix you have to make scripts executable with `chmod`.