# GIT Hooks on Windows with batch

Tags: git, batch-file, githooks

I'm trying to create a git hook rule where commits can be made only if the file `myexamplefile.txt` is changed.

I set my file `.git\hooks\commit-msg` to:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('git status ^| find /c "AssemblyInfo.cs"') do set x=%i
if %x% (
    echo "nice"
    exit 0
)
else (
    echo "it's bad"
    exit 1
)
```

I'm working in this code for a while but I'm getting several errors, right now I'm getting:

> line 28: syntax error near unexpected token `"tokens=*"'

How can I wrote this hook? Is important to notice that I'm in windows environment.

Comment: In a Batch file use double percent-signs in `%%i`. The `) else (` construct must be in the same line. The `if %x% (` part have no sense (unless `%x%` have a valid `if` command comparison). I don't understand how the `myexamplefile.txt` file is related to the posted code...

Comment: I would suggest you open up a cmd prompt and type: `for /?` and `if /?` and read the syntax usage for both commands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any git hooks would be executed by default in a bash session, not a CMD session.
On Windows, the Git for Windows embedded bash would interpret the hook script.

So try and rewrite your hook in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

f=$(git status | grep "AssemblyInfo.cs")
if [[ "${f}" != "" ]]; then
    echo "nice"
    exit 0
else
    echo "darn it"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: way to go above and beyond by rewrite the script in bash

Comment: You could also simply call your batch file from the bash hook, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46701655/63209) or [here](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/636258-git-hooks-on-windows-using-batch).

Comment: @Paul True. I wrote the answer from your first link, but forgot  about it. In the OP's case, I would prefer the bash script approach though.

Comment: @VonC I can see that - it's simpler in bash. Also, just noticed it was you in both answers, haha! Cheers!